# Row lock contention on "CLOB" column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

how to avoid with Row lock contention on "CLOB" column while insert  application logs into oracle database version 11g. also note it is a heavy transaction database we are taking about 30M records per hour

Comment: Are you sure you're getting row lock contention, and not some other kind of wait? If you're only inserting rows there shouldn't be row lock problems. Can you quantify the problem by querying GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY and counting the number of occurrences per event?

Comment: as per as Database admin's feedback, the wait event is due to row lock contention during insertion as Table contains column with datatype CLOB that automatic create unique index  on this column that cause row lock contentions

Comment: CLOBs do automatically create LOB unique indexes, but those indexes are maintained internally as pointers to the CLOB segment and shouldn't generate row locks. For example, `create table test1(a clob)` followed by `insert into test1 values('a');` in multiple sessions will not generate row locks. However, inserting 30M rows per hour could generate other kinds of contention, like hot blocks where multiple processes are writing to the same block and have to wait. There are solutions to those problems (like scalable sequences), but we'd need hard numbers about wait events to properly troubleshoot.

Comment: After checking database alter logs we found a repeated message “Global Enqueue Services Deadlock detected” and we checked also trace file and found DUMP LOCAL BLOCKER: initiate state dump for DEADLOCK and state the insertion statement used from application side

Comment: If there was a deadlock then that trace file will include the two SQL statements and the relevant DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_ID. I'd guess the problem is related to unindexed foreign keys or having a bitmap index on a transactional table.